# Combinatorial interpretation of moments of usual law

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We can interpret $\mathbb{E}[X^p]$ as the number of pairing of $p$ ordered points when $X$ is a standard Gaussian law.
We can also interpret $\mathbb{E}[X^p]$ as the number of partition of a set of $p$ elements when $X$ is a Poisson law of parameter 1.
There is also an interpretation of the moments of an exponential law.

My question is: Is there a reference where all these informations are regrouped with their proof+some visualisations ?

Thanks

Comment: You might try the book from Lond. Math. Soc. by Nica and Speicher, on free probability, which I found delightful for this particular area. I'm not sure how far it'd help with the visualisations. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-the-combinatorics-of-free-probability/D8FC5F2DCCF6C34BB3164E0C0C29437F

Comment: I'm not familiar with free probability, do you know where I could find a section in this book where they speak of those interpretations ? I tried to find such a section in this book but couldn't find one. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Lectures $1$ builds on some basic algebra required for the setup (you do not need to know anything beyond combinatorics and probability, not *free*). Lectures $2,9,10$ offer you the interpretations, specially $9,10$.

Comment: Thank you very much!